# difference between "is searching for " and "searches"

Tags: present-tense

What is the difference between "he is searching for him" and" he searches for him"?

Is the first expression idiomatic?
Does he "searches for" mean  that the person is always looking to find the other one (like a full time job, it is  not a "hobby")

Comment: Neither of these are idiomatic - they're just regular valid sentences.

Comment: The only difference is that between simple present tense and continuous tense. "Search" can have many meanings: "I'm searching for my car keys" probably means I'm doing that, and only that, at this very second. "I'm searching for a city to move to" means I'm thinking about this search over a long period of time, while also going about my everyday life. You would need more than one sentence to make the meaning clear.